# JS global var is undefined

Tags: javascript

I have 2 js files, test1.js and test2.js
They are loaded like this:

```
<script src="test1.js"></script>
<script src="test2.js"></script>
```

In `test1.js` I have a global var, `var myVar = [];`
I tried to read this var in `test2.js` but I get an **undefined error**.

What may cause this behavior since it's a global var.

Comment: Can you try again with `window.myVar = []`?

Comment: Check if your var is in a scope like on page ready

Comment: That's not true, @Kenny.

Comment: @paokg4: What you're describing doesn't happen provided your `var myVar = [];` is at global scope. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: @31piy No Luck using window

Comment: Given your accepted answer, it would indeed have worked with `window`. Next time, please don't ignore requests for more complete information.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think that when we face a problem we have to use any solution but the proper, even the window.var was a temporary solution the problem was at the declaration of the var and not how to read the var.

Comment: @paokg4: My point wasn't to use `window` (that's an antipattern). My point was that if you'd done that, given your accepted answer, it would have worked. My main point, though, was that the question didn't (and doesn't) provide enough information to answer it without guessing, and you were asked to provide that information well over an hour ago, and still haven't. It's great that someone guessed right, but it's **your** responsibiity when asking for help to provide adequate information and follow-up when asked for it.

Comment: I agree but I think that I described the problem exactly as is, please elaborate more. I am asking only to improve future questions. What else information about my issue in this case would be helpful for you?

Comment: @paokg4: Again: A [mcve] of your actual situation, as it clearly *isn't* as described above. (Note: If you want people to know you've responded to them, use an `@` notification.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A common mistake is if your code is inside a page ready function 
e.g jquery document ready `$(document).ready()`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    foo = '';
    // more code...
    // more functions...
});
```

If this is the case, your var is not global, you wont be able to see your var in your `test2.js` because 
JavaScript has function level variable scope. **There is no other scenario** I can think of that this could happen. Global vars are visible in the scenario you are describing.

So just declare your var outside. Init `myvar` like this:

```
var myVar = [];
```

on top of everything.

Answer (score -2):

Maybe it's how you are calling the variables. Try this:

---

HTML file (remember the scripts order, first you call the `var`, then you work with it):

```
<script src="test1.js"></script>
<script src="test2.js"></script>
```

test1.js:

```
var myVar = [];
```

test2.js:

```
console.log(myVar);
```

In test2.js you can also try [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window):

```
console.log(window.myVar);
```

or, if it is in the global scope, use [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this):

```
console.log(this.myVar);
```